# jsPlumb source endpoint does not move when source container is dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsplumb

Using [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/dom.html), where bonds are created between subdivs that are inside draggable `absolute` positioned containers called `.project`s. These all appear in a large generic container `#container`

Which is set as the default container in the code `jsPlumb.Defaults.Container=$("#container");`

http://jsfiddle.net/wwc7G/5/

Everything works fine in one end but not the other. That is:

- When creating 2 `absolute` positioned `.project` containers with 1
  task `div` in each
- Then making 1 bond connection from 1 task to the other.
- And dragging the `.project` container with the source end point - **the
  source end point does not move**.

Why is that the case?
When I make a cyclic bond from 1 task to the other and vice versa and move each `.project`, it all works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update connections of child(DIV) elements you need to make use of customised jQuery draggable instead of jsPlumb.draggable. Here is the customised jQuery draggable for your code:

```
newAgent.draggable({
        containment: 'parent',
        drag:function(e){
            $(this).find('._jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor_').each(function(i,e){ 
                if($(e).hasClass("connect"))
                    jsPlumb.repaint($(e).parent());
                else
                    jsPlumb.repaint($(e));
            });                                     
        }
    });
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrpruthvi/wwc7G/6/)

Comment: I tried this out and this does not work for ne. I am using jQuery ui 1.9.2 and jQuery 1.8.3 along with jsPlumb 1.3.16-all-min.js. Should I be using other soucre files

Comment: I copied the code in the jsFiddle above. The only thing I addded were the three js files I mentioned above