# jsPlumb endpoints not updated when div moves without being dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I'm using [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/dom.html). I have `.project` containers which hold `.task` divs. These `.task` divs are sources/targets for jsPlumb connections. The `.project` containers are draggable.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Af7s/

The `.task` div is assigned the source/target property when it is created (*created using jQuery*):

> ```
>  // Makes the task div a possible target (i.e. connection can be dragged to)
>  jsPlumb.makeTarget(newState, {
>    anchor:["Continuous", { faces:["left", "right"] } ]
>  });
>
>  // Makes the task div a possible source (i.e. connection can be dragged from)
>  jsPlumb.makeSource(newState, {
>    anchor:["Continuous", { faces:["left", "right"] } ]
>  });
> ```

Where the `.task` is the `newState`

> ```
>  var newState = $('<div>').attr('id', id).addClass('task')
> ```

Now to delete a task I have a static button that just detaches all connections to that task and removes it:

> ```
>  $('#removetask1').click(function(e) {
>      jsPlumb.detachAllConnections($('#task1'));
>      $('#task1').remove();
>      //jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
>  })
> ```

The problem occurs when other `task`s shift upward if the deleted `task` div was at the top of the `project`

Also, adding the line (i.e. uncommenting):

> ```
>  jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
> ```

To the end of the remove function call fixes the problem, however the **problem still persists** when the `.project` div is dragged.

---

Before `task1` is deleted:

[image]

After `task1` is deleted `task2` shifts upward and takes its place, but the connection still assumes `task2` is at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: Go through the fiddle link of this SO link, you might get some idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882199/jsplumb-source-endpoint-does-not-move-when-source-container-is-dragged

Comment: Thanks, I have come across that link, though with that jQuery.draggable  it works unexpectedly in my case (sometimes it works, many other times it stops other elements from responding).

Comment: that's sad, what happened to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Detaching all connections before deleting an element and then redrawing the rest of the connections again can help.
Don't forget to store connections data on a side (without those that have to be removed with the element), then run

```
jsPlumb.detachEveryConnection();
```

Remove the element and then jsPlumb.connect({...}) for each connection you've saved prior to this.

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kvtbffrj/