# jsplumb endpoint not update drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop, jsplumb

I want to simply add new nodes by clicking a button (I have the code from [jsPlumb source endpoint does not move when source container is dragged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882199/jsplumb-source-endpoint-does-not-move-when-source-container-is-dragged), I've tried the suggested answer but still not working for me).

Unfortunately, when I drag the new node, the endpoint (that should stick with the overlay) has not updated its position.
the endpoint will update its position after I mouseover the endpoint.

here is the fiddle

`$('#addNode').click(function (e) {
        var newAgent = $('').attr('id', 'flowchartWindow' + num).addClass("window singleFirst");
        newAgent.text('New Node ' + num);

```
    $('#flowchart-demo').append(newAgent);

    _addEndpoints(newAgent, [], ["TopCenter"]);

    newAgent.draggable({
        containment: 'parent',
        drag: function (e) { $(this).find('._jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor_').each(function (i, e) {
                jsPlumb.repaint($(e).parent());
            });
        }
    });

    num++;
});`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ao1odjp/2

(pardon my messy code. I'm trying to combine sample demo (flowchart) from the official jsplumb page and the code I have from stackoverflow above)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

`newAgent.draggable(...`

with

`instance.draggable(newAgent, ...`

Updated jsFiddle project is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3ao1odjp/5/)